# how can I create this type of menu and call on Hover action in android?

Tags: android, popupmenu, mousehover

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jDNPj.jpg)
I want to create custom menu like this. Can anyone help me???

Here is my java side implementation. ivPricePopupMenu is ImageView object and productlist_popup_menu is layout which I want to display on onMouseHover action. Suggest some solutions.

```
ivPricePopupMenu.setOnHoverListener(new View.OnHoverListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onHover(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                Log.d("hover", "Bring yor cursor over the button");
                if(event.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_HOVER_ENTER)
                {
                    //instantiate the popup.xml layout file
                    LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) ProductListActivity.this.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                    View customView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.productlist_popup_menu,null);

                    //instantiate popup window
                   PopupWindow popupWindow = new PopupWindow(customView, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

                    //display the popup window
                    popupWindow.showAtLocation(linearLayout, Gravity.CENTER,0, 0);
                }
                return false;
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hover menu or tooltip kind of view can be implemented using `PopupWindow` widget.

`PopupWindow(context)`

Create the required **XML** layout file for the PopupWindow. Inflate the layout using `LayoutInflater` and set the required data to it.

Calculate the x and y coordinates based on the anchor view's location on screen (i.e., the info button view in the image from the question) to position the pop-up window.

Show the pop-up window using `showAtLocation` method.

```
popUpWindow.showAtLocation(anchorView, gravity, x, y)
```

*gravity* can be set to `Gravity.NO_GRAVITY` by calculating x and y coordinates correctly.

Comment: Explain further, where did you get the exception

Comment: on method call, ivPricePopupMenu.setOnHoverListener(new View.OnHoverListener() { } in this line I got exception

Comment: It gives this error - Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ImageView.setOnHoverListener(android.view.View$OnHoverListener)' on a null object reference

Comment: use either onclick listener or touch listener

Answer (score 2):

I got the Solution!!! Create separate layout file for popupWindow and than use onClickListner event to call that window. create this method in button or image onClick event.

private void initiatePopupWindow() {
            //instantiate the popup.xml layout file
            LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) ProductListActivity.this.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            View customView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.productlist_popup_menu,null);

```
        //instantiate popup window
        final PopupWindow popupWindow = new PopupWindow(customView, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

        popupWindow.setFocusable(true);
        popupWindow.setTouchable(true);
        popupWindow.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable());
        popupWindow.setOutsideTouchable(true);

        //display the popup window
        popupWindow.showAtLocation(buttonTestingLayout, Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);

    }
```